# Updating value in a html table django + bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I have a design with twitter bootstrap front-end and django backend, and I want to make on a shopcart a "plus/minus" button to update quantity and price. How would be the best option to do this? 
Currently I am using a form with 2 buttons and updating the quantity and price values within the view. If I use Jscript how can I update the session fields quantiy and price ?

I want to achieve this : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/buttons-minus-and-plus-in-input but when clicking plus/minus to have price updated according to the quantity values.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript** can be used to update the price based on the quantity.

**Django** only does updates when you submit data to the database.  You can make a shopping cart object in the database of coarse and save what the User has selected in that cart.  But for updates on the page for the price and quantity without submitting data to the database it would be **Javascript**.

I recommend using **Javascript** on the page for price and quantity updates, and then when they select an "add-to-cart" button, then to submit the data like any other `Django Form`, and save the data in a shopping cart for that User's session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use sessions for the cart, but once in the shopping cart ( previous checkout ), how can I handle the updates ?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your situation a simple jquery function for when quantity element is changed will suffice.

for example something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quantity").change(function(){
        q = document.getElementById("quantity").val()
        p = document.getElementById("price").val()
        t = p*q
        document.getElementById("total").val(t)

    });
});
```